# highlight lines with specific syntax in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse to highlight lines with specific syntax? 
Like for example, I want all lines starting with `Log.*`... to be highlighted all the time. The annotations, syntax coloring and other formatting settings do not allow addition of other markings besides from the preset syntaxes.

Comment: What do you _really_ want? You are trying to describe a solution already. Do you want to forbid calls to the Log framework? Do you want to easily find all references to the Log framework? Do you...

Comment: "Do you want to easily find all references to the Log framework?" --actually, that's it. I just want to see all Log.*lines highlighted all the time so that whenever I go over my codes, I can easily spot them without having to search for them (`ctrl+f` or `ctrl+h`). Is there a plugin or something for this? I can't find any...

Comment: I assume that nearly _everyone else_ just uses Ctrl-Shift-G (Search for references) whenever there is a need to actually see the references to some Java identifier. In Eclipse the only "permanent highlighting" are the search result markers, so your only choices seem to be file search or Java (reference) search.

Answer (score 2):

In you file press control-H, 
then click file search tab. (the left most one)
then search Log.(